# Image upload performance issue with Amazon S3 and jqueryfileupload plugin

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I have another issue with amazon and its related to file uploads.I am using [jqueryFileUpload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and amazon API's to uplaod files to amazon S3.I have succeeded in uploading it,but it involves a trick.
     I had to store the image on my server and then move it to S3 from there using `putObjectFile` method of S3.Now the plugin comes with great functions to crop/resize images and I have been using them since long.Now when I integrate the plugin with AWS,i am facing **performance issues** with upload.The time taken for uploads is longer than normal and this raises questions of us using AWS S3 over traditional way.
     I had to make changes to my [UploadHandler.php](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php) file to make it work.These are the changes made.i added a part of AWS upload code to the file from line **735 to 750**

```
     $bucket = "elasticbeanstalk-2-66938761981";
     $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
     $response = $s3->putObjectFile($file_path,$bucket,$file->name,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
     $thumbResponse = $s3->putObjectFile('files/thumbnail/'.$file->name,$bucket,'images/'.$file->name,S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
     //echo $response;
     //echo $thumbResponse;
     if ($response==1) {
        //echo 'HERER enter!!';
     } else {
          $file->error = "<strong>Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.</strong>";
     }
     return $file;
```

[Here](https://github.com/mackstann/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/S3.php) is a link to s3 class on git.
The normal upload to my current server(not amazon),same image uploads in **15 secs**,but on amazon S3 it takes around **23 secs** and I am not able to figure out a better solution.I have to store the image on my sever before uploading to S3 as I am not sure if I can process them **on the fly** and upload directly to S3.
Can anyone suggest the right way to approach the problem?Is it possible to resize the images to different sizes in memory and upload directly to S3 avoiding the overhead of saving it to our server?If yes can anyone guide me in the right direction?
Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Are you using an EC2 instance on Amazon? If so, is it in the same region as your S3 bucket? Which instance type? I handle image resizing in a similar way and it doesn't take that 23 secs, even for large images.

Comment: @user1091949 They are in the same region us-east.May be bandwidth can be an issue!For me its variable between 1mbps-2mbps.Your say?

Comment: How big are the images? Also, is the 23secs the length of time to transfer from your computer, plus the time it takes to resize?

Comment: The size may vary...The numbers I have put are for images upto 2 mb and around.But the application has no restriction for size yet(may be we have it later to around 10-12 mb) as it is in development right now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the approximate 8secs is the overhead here for creating versions of image in different sizes.
You may take different approaches to get rid of the resizing overhead at time of upload. The basic idea will be to allow the uploading script to finish execution and return the response, and do the resizing process as a separate script.

I like to suggest following approaches:
 Approach 1. Don't resize during the upload! Create resized versions on-the-fly only when it is being requested for the first time and cache the generated images to serve directly for later requests. I saw a few mentions of Amazon CloudFront as a solution in some [other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985397/using-aws-s3-for-photo-storage) in Stackoverflow.

Approach 2. Invoke the code for creating resized versions as a separate asynchronous request after the upload of original image. There will be a delay in scaled versions being available. So write necessary code to show some place holder images in the website until the scaled versions become available. You will have to figure out some way to identify whether scaled version is available yet or not(For example check file is existing, or set some flag in database). Some ways for [making asynchronous cURL requests are suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453192/is-making-asynchronous-http-requests-possible-with-php) if you would like to try it out.

I think both approaches will have equal level of complexity.

Some other approaches are suggested as [answers for this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985397/using-aws-s3-for-photo-storage).

Comment: I will study both the approaches rineez.The first looks more apt but will need a POC to check the use.Actually I ask the user to select a size from a set of defined sizes like `original,1024x768,800x600,100x100` and then I show the image.So I will have to keep them ready before the user selects the options.That's what I do,I create the versions before the user can select and when he selects they come up easily.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062246/how-to-replace-php-imagecopyresampled-with-amazon-s3?lq=1) question says something about image resizing and **in memory representation**,but I did not get how can I implement it in my scenario.